# Простая, но нерешенная задача с ACMP. C++

Tags: c++, олимпиада

Условие [задачи](https://acmp.ru/asp/do/index.asp?main=task&id_course=1&id_section=3&id_topic=34&id_problem=210):

> Вклад в банке составляет X рублей. Ежегодно он увеличивается на P
> процентов, после чего дробная часть копеек отбрасывается.
>
> Требуется определить: через сколько лет вклад составит не менее Y
> рублей.
>
> Входные данные Входной файл INPUT.TXT содержит три натуральных числа:
> X, P и Y (X,Y ≤ 1000, P ≤ 100).
>
> Выходные данные В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT выведите целое число –
> ответ на задачу.

Код решения:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x, p, y, cnt = 0;
    cin >> x >> p >> y;
    while (x < y)
    {
        x *= 1 + p / 100.0;
        cnt++;
    }
    cout << cnt;
}
```

Решение не зачлось. Проблема с плавающей точкой? в строке `x *= 1 + p / 100.0` ошибок с кастами точно нет (на 99%) проверил. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Плавающая точка здесь вообще не нужна. Работать в копейках.

```
int x, p, y, cnt = 0;
cin >> x >> p >> y;

x = x * 100;
y = y * 100;
p = p + 100;
while (x < y)
{
    x = (x * p) / 100;
    cnt++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
int x, p, y, cnt = 0;
cin >> x >> p >> y;

x = x * 100;
y = y * 100;
p = p + 100;
while (x < y)
{
    x = (x * p) / 100;
    cnt++;
}
cout << cnt;
    return 0;
}
```

А где инклюды?

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: В такой ситуации лучше редактировать существующий ответ, а не писать свой.